# OpenCV 3.0 installation error

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04

While trying to install OpenCV 3.0 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine I get the following errors:

```
/home/isenses/Documents/opencv-3.0.0-rc1/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:53:21: fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated

modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4295: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Please advise.

Comment: OTOH, `sudo apt-get build-dep opencv`?

Comment: Why are you installing 3.0.0-rc1? [3.1.0](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) is the latest version...

Answer (score 0):

you're missing gstreamer includes. You have to install GStreamer SDK first

[from here](http://gstreamer.com/)